# Bootstrap 3 for SharePoint 2013 installation

Tags: sharepoint, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to install Twitter-Bootstrap 3 on a 2013 SharePoint site. I can't seem to install it properly (Col-*-* class isn't recognized therefore pages aren't responsive) and I can't find any documentation that may help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

There are many 3rd party sources available for Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.0 integrated into SharePoint 2013 for a site with Publishing enabled.

You can check: 
https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/112845

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1db1094e-6f83-418a-ba6f-c339a67e59e0/twitter-bootstrap-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointcustomization